# Is Vamana blinding Shukracharya a canonical story?

Tags: vamana, shukracharya

It is said that Shukracharya knew Vamana's intent when he came to ask for alms from Mahabali Chakravarti.  He took the form of a bee and blocked the spout of the vessel Bali was trying to pour the water out of to consecrate his almsgiving.

Apparently Vamana took a twig and stuck it into the spout and blinded Shukracharya in one eye.

Does this story appear in canonical scripture?

Comment: As far i know, this story is absent in scriptures..

Comment: Shukracharya took the form of a bee to block the spout of the vessel that had the consecrating water.  I don't know if Vamana used a twig or a blade of darbha grass   @blue_ego

Comment: https://www.hinduismfacts.org/dashavatara/vamana-avatar/  @blue_ego

Comment: so i am reading it.  the question is mixed up.  vamana was the pourer, not bali. "Vamana tilted his kamandalu to pour water on the hands of Bali."

Comment: I remember reading in Narasimha Purana

Comment: This story has phallic undertones...shukra dhatu (semen)..

Comment: art is showing the pouring by either bali or vamana, so multiple versions